# Count distinct values and add the value numbers in another excel workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I wanted to try if I have list of values in Column say ("A") which caries repeatable's now I need to count how many are repeatable and add those numbers in another workbook 2 showing same value under Range ("B") for which values notified in Range ("A") of WRKbook1.

This is somewhat difficult think so, But tried using Pivot table unfortunately i didn't helped me much.

For example: Work Book 1 (Sheet1) given as:

```
ColA:

AA  
AA  
AA  
AB  
AB  
AB  
AC  
AC  
AC  
AC
```

Now we all know that number of AA's =3, AB's=3, AC's=4 now the another workbook say wrkbk(2) also given as:

```
ColA:
AA
AB
AC
```

Now need to show on wrkbk(2) as:

```
ColA:  ColB:
AA  3
AB  3
AC  4
```

So this is the place of representing ColB of wrkbk(2) updating?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Hi have you tried the function countif

In workbook b column b assuming AA Is cell A1 then type as follows =COUNTIF(Sheet1!A:A,A1)

http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/countif-HP005209029.aspx

First copy all the rows from sheet1 to sheet2 and goto the data tab and hit remove duplicates then use the above formula

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response! Here in this case assume I dont wanted to perform action by using data tab key; all is when I click or resquested macro button on workbook2 it will copy numbers of how many are repeatable's in column A of workbook 1 and paste the numbers in column B of workbook 2. For this I tried writing the macro code but somehow I got stuck.

Comment: Sub foo()
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

'# Openning both workbooks first:
Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\My\Desktop\Workbooks\Book1")
Set y = Workbooks.Open(":\Users\My\Desktop\Workbooks\Book2")

'Count the number of repeatbles from Workbook 1 and pating number in Wrkbook2

COUNTIF([X.xls](Sheet1!$A:$A,A1:A10)= COUNTIF([Y.xls](Sheet1!$B:$B,B1:B3)


'Close x:
x.Close
Y.Close

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

I have amended your code as follows:

```
Sub foo()
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook
'# Openning both workbooks first:
Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ax1jk3\Desktop\Workbooks\Book3")
Set y = Workbooks.Open(":\Users\ax1jk3\Desktop\Workbooks\Book2")

    'Navigate to the first WOrkBook
    Windows("Book2").Activate
    'Find all the Rown in Range A that you need to copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & Rows.Count.End(xlUp).Row).Select
    Selection.Copy
    'Navigate to the Other WOrkBook
    Windows("Book3").Activate
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    'This will remove the Duplicates
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$" & Rows.Count.End(xlUp).Row).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF([Book12]Sheet1!C1,RC[-1])"
    Range("B1").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B1:B" & Rows.Count.End(xlUp).Row)
    Range("B1:B" & Rows.Count.End(xlUp).Row).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False


'Close x:
x.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi execution failing of using Invalid qualifier:? Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & Rows.Count.End(xlUp).Row).Select

Comment: Okay, I figured out by removing's' in rows. but we need object required? it is asking me object required? thanks!